# Flutter ListView inside a Columns is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a list view inside a column but it crashes

I have got the following Errors:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints
>   are unbounded.
>
> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#e1a1e relayoutBoundary=up7
>   NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>   'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1687
>   pos 12: 'hasSize'
>
> The method '>' was called on null. Receiver: null

This is my Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CheckinAccessories extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckinAccessoriesState createState() => _CheckinAccessoriesState();
}

class _CheckinAccessoriesState extends State<CheckinAccessories> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0XFF3a6fd8),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[backButton(), welcomeText(), mainContent()],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 60.0,
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          color: Color(0XFF3a6fd8),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: Text('Next', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container backButton() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton.icon(
              color: Color(0XFF265abf),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              label: Text('Back',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container welcomeText() {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg_car.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.contain)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Accessories',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    height: 1.3)),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Container mainContent() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(50), topRight: Radius.circular(50)),
        color: Color(0XFFedeff1),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Accessories List',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Color(0XFF132758)),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              CheckboxWidget()
            ],
          )

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CheckboxWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CheckboxWidgetState createState() => new CheckboxWidgetState();
}

class CheckboxWidgetState extends State {
  Map<String, bool> values = {
    'Apple': false,
    'Banana': false,
    'Cherry': false,
    'Mango': false,
    'Orange': false,
  };

  var tmpArray = [];

  getCheckboxItems() {
    values.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value == true) {
        tmpArray.add(key);
      }
    });

    // Printing all selected items on Terminal screen.
    print(tmpArray);
    // Here you will get all your selected Checkbox items.

    // Clear array after use.
    tmpArray.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return Column(
    //   children: <Widget>[
    //     Text('test')
    //   ],
    // );
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Text('test'),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(

          children: values.keys.map((String key) {
            return new CheckboxListTile(
              title: new Text(key),
              value: values[key],
              activeColor: Colors.pink,
              checkColor: Colors.white,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  values[key] = value;
                });
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things you need to understand first.

**Column** takes as much height as it can get. Since in your case **Column** doesn't have a height neither does it have a parent to constrain it's height. So your column takes **INFINITE** height.

Further more **Expanded** has similar functionality as that of column in regards to the feature that **Expanded** is supposed to take up all the space remaining out the height of it's parent. For e.g. if you have

```
Container(
    height: 400,
    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
    Text('test'),
    Expanded(
      child: ...
    ),
  ]),
)
```

If the **Text** takes up 50 then the rest of the height will be assigned to **Expanded**

And since in your case **Column** already takes **INFINITE** height **Expanded** will get the remaining except Text which again is **INFINITE**.

**The Solution:**

Wrap your Column with a container and then use any one of the two:

1. and give it a fixed height.
2. if you want dynamic height then [check out the **MediaQuery** Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your detailed reply, I have solved it  by giving a fixed height to the container.

Comment: Good to know that it helped.